# no classes added when ACF Select is selected

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Created an ACF field with select where the user can choose the color of the card. Wrote a condition that adds a class with a color when selected in the select. Now the code doesn't work, and var_dump() returns NULL. How can this be fixed?

```html
<?php

$colors = get_field("colors");
var_dump($colors);

$colortext = '';

if ($colors == 'yellow') {
    $colortext = 'yellow-article-bg';
} else if ($colors == 'green') {
    $colortext = 'green-article-bg';
} else if ($colors == 'blue') {
    $colortext = 'blue-article-bg';
} else if ($colors == 'dark blue') {
    $colortext = 'dark-blue-article-bg';
} else if ($colors == 'grey') {
    $colortext = 'grey-article-bg';
}

?>


  <?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                    $case = new WP_Query(array(
                        'post_type' => 'post',
                        'paged' => $paged,
                        'order'  => 'DESC',
                        'posts_per_page' => 12,
                        'post_parent'  =>   $cats
                    ));                      
                    while ($case->have_posts()) : $case->the_post(); ?>
  <article class="<?php echo $colortext ?>">
    ...
  </article>
  <?php endwhile;
                    wp_reset_postdata();  ?>
```

Comment: Where did you store this, and what is the context of the code you have shown us? You are not passing any id to the function, so it will fall back onto the current global post ID (if that is already set at this point.)

Comment: Your edited code shows that you are getting `colors` *before* you get the posts. If you have added the ACF field to the posts, then you need to call `get_field` in your loop on each post individually.